# Visual Studio 2022 not able to find/install package Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

Tags: c#, .net

I am following along a Tutorial to add Authentication and Authorization in Blazor Webassembly Application. The sample code for this tutorial uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, however, I am not able to find this package in Visual Studio 2022 or install it using Package Manager Console. I would appreciate advice on how to sort this. Thank you.

Comment: What error are you seeing if any? I just opened a plain console app, went to Nuget Package Manager, selected `browse` and typed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization`...there it was with 11million downloads. What are you seeing in Package Manager.
This is your package manager command `NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization -Version 7.0.4`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I have tried the command you have suggested and I get the following error message

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'BlazorEcommerce.Server'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization -Versio ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Can you update your post to include that  error

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the target .NET version your project is set up for. If it's .NET8, you need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization` **v8.x**. If your project targets eg. .NET6, you need to install `...Authorization` **v6.x**.

Example .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="6.0.26" />
    </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```